Does react-native-navigation work completely on Main Thread? Will it work if JS thread is blocked?
Currently I am working on a app which does a lot of background tasks due to which JS thread is blocked for long time. Now currently I am using react-navigation/native-stack and react-navigation/bottom-tabs for navigation. When the JS thread is blocked I am not able to switch between tabs quickly and it takes 5 to 10 seconds to do it. This happens because react-navigation lib base code works on JS thread. If I use react-native-navigation library will it solve my issue? Does all the UI interactions in react-native-navigation library work on Main thread? If the JS thread is blocked will react-native-navigation work properly? I would really appreciate your guidance.
These are the libraries i am using currently:
react-navigation/bottom-tabs
react-navigation/native
react-navigation/native-stack

Yes,
It will work while JS thread is blocked.
